# OpenSaml read metadata

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

I'm tring to read the metadata from an Idp using Open Saml 2. When i try to unmarshall the metadata openSaml show only this getter  for attributes get**Unknown**Atrributes(). Looks like i am missing some point since when reading the Idp response SAML the code works very well. (it shows getAssertions() that returns a list of assertions).

I need to parse the metadata and find informations regarding the Idp.

Here the method

```
     public Metadata metadataReader() {

        ByteArrayInputStream bytesIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(ISSUER_METADATA_URL.getBytes());
        BasicParserPool ppMgr = new BasicParserPool();

        ppMgr.setNamespaceAware(true);
        // grab the xml file
//      File xmlFile = new File(this.file);
        Metadata metadata = null;
        try {
            Document document = ppMgr.parse(bytesIn);
            Element metadataRoot = document.getDocumentElement();
            QName qName = new QName(metadataRoot.getNamespaceURI(), metadataRoot.getLocalName(),
                    metadataRoot.getPrefix());
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory().getUnmarshaller(qName);
            metadata = (Metadata) unmarshaller.unmarshall(metadataRoot);


            return metadata;

        } catch (XMLParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnmarshallingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a metadata provider to do the heavy lifting for you. FilesystemMetadataProvider is often a good fit.

I have a [blog post](http://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/02/reading-metadata-with-opensaml.html) that explains how to use it.

Comment: When i try to use your code i get  Metadata provider failed to properly initialize, fail-fast=true, halting
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Saw an error of type 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' with message 'org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal'. And i can't undestand also how to get SingleLogoutService informations.

Comment: looks like a dependency problem. Getting SLO is the same as getting SSO in the post. Just get SingleLogoutService instead of SingleSignOnService